# Not getting my program to print to output file

Tags: c

I must solve a problem to sort a double array in ascending order using selection sort. I must do the sort by finding the largest number on each pass.
this is the code I used

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE*in=fopen("input.txt","r");
    FILE*out=fopen("output.txt","w");
    double n[10];
    void selectionSort(double[],int,int);
    for(int j=0;j<=9;j++)
    fscanf(in,"%lf",n[j]);
    selectionSort(n,0,9);
    for(int r=0;r<=9;r++)
    fprintf(out,"%f\n",n[r]);
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}

int getBiggest(double n[],int lo,int hi){
    int big=lo;
    for(int j=lo+1;j<=hi;j++)
        if(n[j]>n[big])big=j;
    return big;}

    void swap(double n[],int i,int j){
        double hold=n[i];
        n[i]=n[j];
        n[j]=hold;}

    void selectionSort(double n[],int lo,int hi){
        int getBiggest(double[],int,int);
        void swap(double[],int,int);
        for(int j=lo;j<hi;hi--){
            int b =getBiggest(n,j,hi);
        swap(n,hi,b);}
    }
```

When I compile the program the file output.txt is created but remains empty. I did get a warning saying format '%lf' expects argument of type 'double *',but argument 3 has type 'do...
I'm really new to coding so I don't know why the program isn't working.

Comment: When a program isn't working what you should do is debug it and not just post on SO straight away. Run your program in a debugger and/or add more debug print statements to trace the program execution. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Oops,  saw what was wrong. Yeah, I shouldn't be so hasty to post.

Answer (score 0):

> '%lf' expects argument of type 'double *',but argument 3 has type 'do..

The desired `double *` is a pointer.  `n[j]` is a `double`, not a pointer.

```
double n[10];
// fscanf(in,"%lf",n[j]); -->
fscanf(in, "%lf", &n[j]);
```

Enable all warnings and review them carefully.